# access denied when trying to access database using root issue

Tags: mysql

I have the following error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user 'root'@'%' to database 'GUEST_BOOK'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
```

previously I have done:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON GUEST_BOOK.* TO 'root@%' IDENTIFIED BY 'D7n()st1234' WITH GRANT OPTION;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

not sure why it is still giving me that permission error? Any idea?

Comment: Can you connect as root via mysql cli?

Comment: yes I can... and by the way I am doing this remotely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'root@%'` is different than `'root'@'%'` in SQL terms

Essentially writing 'root@%' probably created an entry for a user called 'root@%' and not a user named root who would be accessing via any means (%)

Update your grant statement to read

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON GUEST_BOOK.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'D7n()st1234' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: so what should I do then? is this a typo on that grant all ?

Comment: yes sorry, update your GRANT ALL to say 'root'@'%' i have done this many times myself :)